# svn - when will I see conflicts?

Tags: version-control, git, svn, change, ubuntu

I am just starting a new position and using **svn** rather than **git** (my favorite).

With **svn** if there are any conflicts will I see them after an svn update or after an (attempt) to svn commit?

In other words will an **svn update** merge remote changes into my current (uncommited) working copy?

I want to be sure not to mess up before my first **svn commit** if things are not good as I am new to this system! :)

Obviously I have also made a manual copy of my new code in case I run into any issues :)

fyi, I am on Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: It sounds like you would be ideally interested in [git-svn](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-svn.html) - I use this as my Subversion client whenever I can. You can continue to use Git like you always do, and interact with Subversion only when you need to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In other words will an svn update merge remote changes into my current (uncommited) working copy?

Yes.

svn will not let you `commit` if there are new changes in the repository; you will have to do an `update` first. This `update` will merge remote changes into your current working copy and alert you of any merge conflicts that occurred.

Comment: yeah I found this too: http://wiki.greenstone.org/wiki/index.php/Useful_SVN_Commands

Comment: Most significatly An svn update merges the repository's changes with the local changed code, or shows places where conflicts have arisen (conflicts are shown with a C next to the files you tried to update). If someone else had committed changes to the repository and if these did not conflict with the changes in your own version, the svn update would show up a "G", not a "C". To deal with conflicts (C), see a later section.

Comment: I also just got a better understanding that, unlike git, there is no 'local' repository, so 'commit' goes straight to the remote server instead of doing 'commit' and 'push' as in git.  As I now understand it, in svn 'push' therefore doesn't exist.

Comment: Correct, there is no "svn push".  And FYI, Subversion uses the term "conflict" differently from how you are.  In Subversion, a "conflict" is the result of merging change(s) into your working copy that Subversion was not able to automatically resolve (probably because you changed the same line(s)).  Your "conflicts" are just "other commits" to Subversion.

Welcome to the past! :-)